# Is Ann Walker suffering from PTSD or DID or both?

Tags: character, gentleman-jack

In the BBC ONE/HBO series [*Gentleman Jack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman_Jack_(TV_series)), the character Ann Walker seems to suffer greatly from a series of traumatic events, including loosing most of her immediate family (older brother, a sister, and her parents) to possible sexual assault.

She is often sited as having "nerves" and it isn't until she becomes more acquainted with Anne Lister and engages in a more serious relationship, that she seems able to be more confident, making her opinions more known, up until a point where Miss Lister offers her a bit of an ultimatum (a time limit) to secretly get married and have Anne come live with her on her estate at Shibden Hall.

Upon the rejection, seemingly feeling very pressured, Ann Walker seems to become more mentally unstable, as she begins to have nightmares about her and Miss Lister facing the nose and where she begins to hear voices, like that from the crowd in her nightmare, jeering and being contempt towards her. She explains later once Miss Lister visits and spends the night, that these voices are coming from the clock in the hall and begins to become obsessed with verbally stating Bible verses asking for forgiveness.

It's examination of mental illness is one of many unique topical things that set *Gentleman Jack* apart from most typical 'British period romance' flare!

But I was wondering if it was at all stated anywhere by the Creator, Executive Producer, Director, and writer Sally Wainwright or any in the cast, **what exactly Ann Walker suffers from?**

Is it Post Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD) or Disassociate Identity Disorder (DID), or is it possibly both, as I believe I have read articles that there can be a correlation between the two?

---

Note: I'm also aware that both of these women are based on real-life women who existed, but I don't know how much liberty the TV series has taken and if the real Ann Walker also suffered from a similar condition, although I believe she was later institutionalized, but I would be interested in those answers as well.